# Como inserir um set time em uma função

Tags: javascript, html

A função desse código abaixo e seguinte apos eu clicar em um submit de um form ele redireciona para uma outra pagina esta funcionado agora só preciso que ele só redirecione para outra pagina apos, *5 segundos* alguém sabe como fazer isso manjo muito pouco de javascript?

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  window.location = 'minha URL';
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout`

Comment: Você pode me mostrar como ficaria o código

Comment: Utilize `setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'minha URL'; }, 5000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'minha URL'; }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar `setTimeout()`

Faça assim:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'minha URL';
    }, 5000);
}
```

Após clicar no botão será executa a função `setTimeout()` que recebe uma função a ser executada e o tempo em milissegundos, após esse tempo ela executa a função passada.

Você ainda pode atribuir a função á uma variável para poder cancelar depois, para isso você utilizaria a função `clearTimeout()` recebendo a variável com a função a ser cancelada:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'minha URL';
    }, 5000);

    //Parar timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```